# HashSet filtering in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a method that searches for people in my database. I would like to refactor it so that it makes use of hashsets to increase the performance.

I've made a simplified example below (which won't compile, but just to give you an idea).

Is it possible to use a `HashSet` in my example?

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
{
    var persons = new HashSet<PERSON>(context.PERSON);

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(age))
    {
        persons = persons.Where(p => p.age == age);
    }

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        persons = persons.Where(p => p.name.StartsWith(name));
    }
    //some similar filtering...

    return persons.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Warning! You will run out of memory if the person table is too larger since all persons will be loaded to memory. Just let the DB do the filtering for you. If the query is slow, check your query and use indexes.

Comment: it can be used. did you face any problem?

Comment: @Rezoan HashSets doens't have a Where() method, so yes, I did face a problem.

Comment: @Johan I did not understand. I have used Where() so many time in HashSet. it's an extension method. if it does not appear try to use: yourhashSetObject.AsEnumareable().

Comment: @Rezoan Correct me if I'm wrong here, but as soon as I do `.Where()` on my set, it will become an `IEnumerable` instead of `HashSet`. Thus it would be pointless to declare it as a hashset in the first place.

Comment: Well a `HashSet` is designed for storing data so you can lookup *by the hash code* . Whereas you seem to want to lookup by `person.age`. Unless `person.GetHashCode()` is overriden to return the `person.age` in this case, it's probably pointless - you might as well just store them in a `List<Person>` and be done with it because you will have lots of objects with the same hash therefore you have lost the true advantage of using a `HashSet`. Also I second LotInComputer's point.

Comment: @Johan follow the answer of qujck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, the following line of code is not a good idea

```
var persons = new HashSet<PERSON>(context.PERSON);
```

because it will pull all of the data from the `PERSON` `DbSet` and insert it into the `person` object.

Your code is almost as optimised as possible without the overhead of reading all the data into a `HashSet`.

I suggest that you to build up an `IQueryable` object that will fire the relevant tailored Sql to filter your data. Nothing will be read from the database until the point you call `ToList()`

```
var persons = context.PERSON.AsQueryable();

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(age))
{
    persons = persons.Where(p => p.age == age);
}

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
    persons = persons.Where(p => p.name.StartsWith(name));
}
//some similar filtering...

return persons.ToList();
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `.AsQueryable()` and explicitly defining persons as `IQueriable<Person>`? What will happen if my lambda can't be translated in to SQL?

Comment: @Johan there's no difference between the two - `AsQueryable` simply means you can use `var persons`. If you have some filters that cannot be translated to Sql then you'll have to apply those filters *after* the call to `ToList()`. You'd have to build some tests to decide for sure whether a `HashSet` would be of benefit for this but I would suggest it's probably not worth it.

Comment: My initial though was to use HashSets only when comparing two lists of keys to reduce the complexity of the algoritm from `O(N^2)` to `O(N)`. Perhaps I should create HashSets of the keylists and keep the other part as it is (based on your example that is)?